# Vary type of input control based on drop down selection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, jquery-ui

I'm building an edit screen where a use can edit rows of data.  One of the fields is represented by a drop down, and another is an input field named 'value'.  Now, depending on the value in the dropdown, I need to have different kinds of input controls for the value input control.  Sometimes it should be a text box, others a datetime control (html5 and / or jqUI date picker), and finally a dropdown list containing a fixed set of values ('Yes' / 'No').

So basically sometimes I need to accept any string data, sometimes a date, and sometimes a boolean (but with a select box, not a check box).  What's my best option for implementing this?  Ideally the value entered would not be lost moving from one kind of input to another, while the user is on this edit page.  On post back, I have a single database value to store (its a sql_variant).

Also, I'm using asp.net mvc3 so an ideal solution will work with the normal Html.ValidateFor and Html.ValidationMessageFor methods.

Comment: Can you post code? You can change the input type by simply altering the HTML. It is hard to answer this question with no code.

Comment: @natemrice There's no code to post.  I haven't written this yet, and I wanted to ask the question to keep me from going down a path that could be painful in the end.

Comment: @Andy you want to submit this in a form? no big deal. just put the edit fields inside a form and they will all be sent. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot's of time in JSFiddle, I made this solution. And I think it's pretty cool. It wasn't really that hard. and you can adapt it to whatever you need. just click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPTRq/).

basically I make variables to represent the possible values. then I make a variable to hold the active element.

Whenever the type selector changes, it calls the `change()` function which uses `if()` statements to check what was selected, and then it sets the active element accordingly.

And finally, it calls the `hide()` function which hides the inactive elements.

here is the [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/BPTRq/1/)

RED ALERT: I realized this didn't work in FF (maybe it was just my browser but whatever).
 so I fixed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPTRq/3/)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some additional information.  Both answers so far are helpful, but neither are all the way there, which was my fault for no including enough detail.

Comment: This answer is almost exactly what I ended up doing.  The only tweak was a hidden field I used to bind the Model's Value property to, and I copy data into it when the currently visible control changed.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for giving me the bounty

Answer (score 2):

The typical way I accomplish something like this is to actually store 3 different fields in the db for each of the different types of values.  Then I create something like the following html:

```
<!-- Input type selector  -->
<div class="cell variable-selector">
    <select><option ...</select>
</div>
<!-- varied input -->
<div class="cell variable show-text">
    <div class="text"><input type="textbox"></div>
    <div class="date-picker"><input type="textbox" class="datepicker"></div>
    <div class="drop-down-bool"><select><option ...</select>
</div>
```

Then I have css that hides or shows the correct input element based on which class the cell has:

```
div.variable div { display:none }
div.show-text div.text { display: inline }
div.show-date-picker div.date-picker {display: inline }
div.show-drop-down-bool div.drop-down-bool {display: inline}
```

lastly you can setup some javascript so that when you change your variable-selector you change the class of your variable cell.  Which jquery one might do this as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var variableSelector = $("div.variable-selector > select");
    variableSelector.change(function() {
        var type = $(this).text();
        var class = "cell variable show-" + type;
        var variableCell = $(this).parent().parent().find("variable");
        variableCell.attr("class", class);

    })
});
```

As a quick warning I wrote the above code on the fly in the stack overflow editor window so there might be a couple of syntax errors or a minor bug somewhere but the basic idea should work.  Hope it helps.
--Adam

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I assume we'd also need to blank the values for the hidden inputs on submit, otherwise we'd get the values in the controls even if they are hidden.

Comment: Actually I don't delete the values I save all three and also save the value of the variable-selector.  Then if the user switches back at a later date their old value is still there.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some additional information.  Both answers so far are helpful, but neither are all the way there, which was my fault for no including enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to make full use of mvc3 validations, consider this approach.

Model

```
public class MultiValueViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string TextValue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool? BooleanValue { get; set; }

    public MultiValueType ValueType { get; set; }
}

public enum MultiValueType
{
    Text,
    Boolean
}
```

View

```
@model MultiValueViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValueType, new SelectList(new[]
{
    MultiValueType.Text,
    MultiValueType.Boolean
}), new { @id = "multi_value_dropdown" })
<p>
<div data-type="@MultiValueType.Text" class="multi-value-pane">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TextValue)
</div>
<div style="display: none" data-type="@MultiValueType.Boolean" class="multi-value-pane">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BooleanValue, new SelectList
            (new [] {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false"}
            }, "Value", "Text"), optionLabel: "[Not Set]")
</div>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#multi_value_dropdown").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(".multi-value-pane").each(function () {
            $(this).css("display", value == $(this).attr("data-type") ? "block" : "none");
        });
    });
})
```

Inside your controller, receive MultiValueViewModel value (alone or inside parent model), and based on selected ValueType save to database. Please note that you will need jquery.validate version 1.9 if you need to skip validation on hidden fields (e.g. :hidden).